# Contact form shows confirmation on new page instead in div (ajax)

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to get that Contact Form to Work: 
https://bootstrapious.com/p/how-to-build-a-working-bootstrap-contact-form
but the confirmation Text opens in a new site instead of the div "messages".

contact.php

```
    <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="contactaction.php" role="form" data-toggle="validator">
        <div class="messages"></div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/1000hz-bootstrap-validator/0.11.9/validator.min.js"></script>
    <script src="contact.js"></script>
```

contact.js

```
$(function () {

    // init the validator


    $('#contact-form').validator();


    // when the form is submitted
    $('#contact-form').on('submit', function (e) {

        // if the validator does not prevent form submit
        if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
            var url = "contact.php";

            // POST values in the background the the script URL
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data)
                {
                    // data = JSON object that contact.php returns

                    // we recieve the type of the message: success x danger and apply it to the 
                    var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                    var messageText = data.message;

                    // let's compose Bootstrap alert box HTML
                    var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';

                    // If we have messageAlert and messageText
                    if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                        // inject the alert to .messages div in our form
                        $('#contact-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
                        // empty the form
                        $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: What you have in contact.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use e.preventDefault(); as the first step of the onsubmit function:

```
     // when the form is submitted
     $(function () {

        // init the validator
        $('#contact-form').validator();


        // when the form is submitted
        $('#contact-form').on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            // if the validator does not prevent form submit
            var url = "contact.php";

            // POST values in the background the the script URL
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data)
                {
                    // data = JSON object that contact.php returns

                    // we recieve the type of the message: success x danger and apply it to the 
                    var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                    var messageText = data.message;

                    // let's compose Bootstrap alert box HTML
                    var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';

                    // If we have messageAlert and messageText
                    if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                        // inject the alert to .messages div in our form
                        $('#contact-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
                        // empty the form
                        $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        })
    });
```

Comment: There isn't really anything in your contact.php example to go by. I just copied the entire example file html code from what you referred to: https://bootstrapious.com/p/how-to-build-a-working-bootstrap-contact-form
Then added in the script above and it's working for me. At least it's validating and then firing an AJAX call to contact.php.
But you didn't add any code to show what that is meant to do @Bennobear
Perhaps you want to share more code and tell us what's not working